# How to import database sql/csv file using an html button?

Tags: php, html, sql

How can I import database file using an html button?

I tried creating an upload button and tried to upload a imported sql file from database but the data don't go to the database

```
<?php
require "../database.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql_file = $_POST['data'];

    // Read SQL file
    $sql = file_get_contents($sql_file);


    // Execute SQL statements
    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL file imported successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error importing SQL file: ";
    }

    // Close database connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Import Database</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include '../navigation.php';?>

    <div class="container-lg">
    <form action="import.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" class="form-control mt-5" name="data">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Import Database</button>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
this is my code
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using to load the file and to import sql into db?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue. We cannot fix unspecified errors in invisible code. See also [ask]

Comment: Thanks for adding code. But that isn't quite how you process file uploads using php. Have you looked at any tutorials? Start with the one in the php manual - https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score -1):

I think your first problem in definition the sql file : `$sql_file = $_POST['data'];` for definition a file you must to use

```
<?php
    
        $conn =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'blog_samples');
        
        $query = '';
        $sqlScript = file('database-script.sql');
        foreach ($sqlScript as $line)   {
            
            $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0 ,2);
            $endWith = substr(trim($line), -1 ,1);
            
            if (empty($line) || $startWith == '--' || $startWith == '/*' || $startWith == '//') {
                continue;
            }
            
    
    $query = $query . $line;
    if ($endWith == ';') {
        mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('<div class="error-response sql-
        import-response">Problem in executing the SQL query <b>' . $query. '</b></div>');
                $query= '';     
            }
        }
    
        echo '<div class="success-response sql-import-response">SQL file imported successfully</div>';
        ?>
```

The resources from https://phppot.com/php/how-to-import-sql-into-a-database-using-php/

Comment: But the OP wants to use an uploaded SQL script file, not a hard-coded filename pointing to something which is already on the server. This answer simply alters the method of processing the script (which we have no evidence is even needed) rather than addressing the specific problem the OP was experiencing. (Luckily, that problem is actually answered in the PHP manual and many other places already - see comments above).